# Is it possible to use condition for Azure Pipeline Service Containers?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

for example, I have something like this:

```
- job: Build
  dependsOn: CheckTest
  pool: ${{ parameters.setPool }}
  services:
    redis: redis
    rabbitmq: rabbitmq
  steps:
    - checkout: self
```

My question is - is it possible to manage `services` list? For example, for some  cases I need only `redis` container, for another only `rabbitmq` and sometimes I don't need any containers at all. Is it possible to implement dynamic services list?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using object parameters.

Pipeline:

```
parameters:
- name: myObject
  type: object
  default:
    serviceToDeploy:
    - redis
    - rabbitmq

steps:
  - script: echo "Test step before parameter validation"
  - ${{ if ne(length(parameters.myObject.serviceToDeploy), 0) }}:
    - ${{ each service in parameters.myObject.serviceToDeploy }}:
      - script: echo ${{ service }}
        displayName: "Task for installing ${{ service }}"
```

---

Run pipeline with 4 services:

[image]

Result:

[image]

---

Run pipeline with "No" services

[image]

Result:

[image]

*PS: I do not have any container pools to test, but the conditions and loop should work exactly the same*

Answer (score 0):

I would consider choosing with a conditional approach. For example

```
variables:
  ${{ if eq(parameters.Environment, 'Production') }}: 
    serviceToDeploy: redis
  ${{ else }}:
    serviceToDeploy: rabbitmq
```

And then you could use

```
 services:
    service1: $(serviceToDeploy)
```

Comment: In this case, looks like we can`t use both of redis and rabbit at the same time, and the second case - we can`t to use none of them